# How do I look at checked out files from another view in my Clearcase config spec

Tags: clearcase

I wonder how I look at a checked out file from another view.

We are using dynamic views and I can see other views checked out files using clearcase version tree so I think it should be possible to specify in a config spec.

When I check out a file I can see the following information.

```
cleartool lshistory
"20100312.133301" "userid" "/vobs/.../.../File.cpp" "/main/<bransch>/<my_task_brancsh>/CHECKEDOUT" "checkout version" "checkout".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you cannot directly access a CHECKEDOUT version, since the actual content is stored locally (for snapshot views) or in the local View Storage (for dynamic views).

The ClearCase server knows about the CHECKEDOUT status (which is why you see it in the config spec), but won't have its content.

The only way you could access a CHECKEDOUT version would be:

- if the file has been CHECKEDOUT in a dynamic view
- if you can that remote dynamic view from your workstation

Then you will actually see both the dynamic view *and* the storage space of that dynamic view (which, for dynamic views, contains private files and checked out files)

In short, the only way is to somehow access "the other view" (impossible with snapshot views unless you have a physical access to the workstation where the view has been created, possible with dynamic views which can be "mounted" on any ClearCase client)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I can access the other dynamic view and also the view server which the view is located on. Are there any way to access the files from that view without using that view specifically? (I don't want to do cleartool setview other_view)

Comment: @ki_: you don't have to use `setview`: if the other view is started, it is available at `/view/theotherview/vob/...`. But from a local view which is not the one used to make a checkout, no, you cannot access that file.